# How to remove session if server is stopped

Tags: java, session, struts2

I developed the webapplication with Struts2.after logging to the my application copy the url and paste to the same browser with different tab then its going to directly without  restrict.in that situation i want restrict it.

but same url copy and paste to another browser its working fine .only same browser and different Tab then only problem

Comment: any reason why you want to do this??? its really an overhead to do this as here your browser is maintain the session and for your use case you need to make sure generate new session for such use case

Comment: The title of your question has nothing to do with what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your browser has stored your login authentication in the session. It will remember this until you either

- Close all windows of the browser *or*
- Choose **New Session** from the menu

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about your development cycle take a look op answer of @Keppil.

If however you are asking about real user experience this is more complicated. Browser indeed remembers your session ID in cookie and sends it on each request. To override this mechanism you can create your own tokens that will be always appended to URL. 
When token is supplied it should send redirect response to URL without token.
The server side should throw user to login screen every time the token is not supplied and the request is not from redirect.

I have never tried to do this and I am not sure you really want to implement this. The ability of browser to connect to same session even if user opens another tab or browser window is very convenient and widely applicable.